# How should one evaluate this integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

How does one go about evaluating such an integral where E and V are constants?

$\int\sqrt{E-Vx^8}dx$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try: `Integrate[Sqrt[e - v*x^8], x]` works fine.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask on [`Mathematics StackExchange`](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

As @MariuszIwaniuk says, use small letters, not capitals.

If you use assumptions, the result can be simplified: assuming $E>0$,

```
Assuming[e > 0, Integrate[Sqrt[e - v*x^8], x] // FullSimplify]

(*    Sqrt[e]*x*Hypergeometric2F1[-1/2, 1/8, 9/8, v*x^8/e]    *)
```